# Autocannon, can't attach & to query string

Tags: node.js

I'm struggling with invoking the autocannon method on Windows 10.

I have got an API, something like:
`autocannon -c 10 -d 10 https://uri/param1/param2?file=query1&pass=query2`

The problem is, Windows reads the URL string up to `&` sign, and after, it invokes another function, starting from pass=query2

```
'pass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone know how could I attach `&` to the query? I was searching for the solution but nothing came up on this particular problem.

Comment: did you try putting the url in quotes? example: `autocannon -c 10 -d 10 "https://uri/param1/param2?file=query1&pass=query2"`

Comment: That one works good as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after I switched to run the command from the Powershell.

The reason why it didn't work is that Windows cmd uses `&` internally. In order to have it running I needed to wrap `&` in double quotes.

```
autocannon -c 10 -d 10 https://uri/param1/param2?file=query1"&"pass=query2
```